# Interpolation in a Vue component that creates HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a web app using Vue 2.6.x.  In the prototype that was created we have a line like this repeated many times:

```
<label class="title">On Time</label><span class="score float-right">Score: {{ score.ap_ontime }}
```

The only part of this whole line that changes is the data within the `{{` `}}`.  I would like to turn this into a component that I can call many times.  For example:

```
<MyLabel title="On Time" score="score.ap_ontime" />
```

...so that I don't have to type this score interpolation over and over in a long HTML file.  I know how pass props to the component and add text to the template of the component:

```
<template>
...
<label class="title">{{title}}</label>
...
</template>
```

..but what I can't figure out is how to take a string (e.g.`score.ap_ontime`) and have the template inject something that will render that value from a `score` plain old JavaScript object that exists in the application and is imported into the template.  The original code I show at the top of this post renders fine and reacts to changes in the JavaScript object I just can't figure out how to do this in a component that creates HTML and Vue template syntax based on props.

Comment: Are you just asking about a binding?  If so it's `:score="score.ap_ontime"`, notice the `:`

Answer (score 0):

Your new component should look something like this:

```html
<template>
  <label class="title">{{ caption }}</label>
  <span class="score float-right">Score: {{ onTime }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'MyNewComponent',
  props:
  {
    caption:
    {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    onTime:
    {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then you can call your component in this way:

```html
<my-new-component :caption="Big title" :on-time="score.ap_ontime" />
```